# Rails proejct, "Routing Error No route matches "/pages"" Need help

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I folllowed  this :
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec:user_signup
.

But when I try to access http://localhost:3000/pages/  it returns "Routing Error  No route matches "/pages""

This is my routes.rb

```
Sample4App::Application.routes.draw do

    get "users/new"

    match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'

    match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
    match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
    match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'

    match '/', :to => 'pages#home'
end
```

This is my home.html.erb

```
<h1>Sample App</h1>

<p>
  This is the home page for the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  sample application.
</p>

<%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, :class => "signup_button round" %>
```

I tried everything I can. But still.
Really need help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your missing the actual route for '/pages/'. Try adding this to your routes.rb

```
match '/pages' => 'pages#home'
```

Comment: thanks, but not work. acturally ,the root(/`) is mathing 'pages#home'

Comment: Okay, I just assumed that you wanted /pages to be routed to home since you didn't specify. But if that is not correct then what do you want to happen when you are browsing /pages ?

Comment: @Josh Morrison that is right what you want. @DanneManne, `match` better to replace with `get` here

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sample4App::Application.routes.draw do
    get "users/new"

    match 'signup' => 'users#new'

    match 'contact' => 'pages#contact'
    match 'about' => 'pages#about'
    match 'help' => 'pages#help'

    match 'pages' => 'pages#home'

    root :to => 'pages#index'
end
```

And make sure you have `index` action in your `Pages` controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in roots

```
root :to => 'pages#home'
```

So, you can access http://localhost:3000

or add

```
match '/pages',    :to => 'pages#home'
```

so you can  access http://localhost:3000/pages

Comment: check with rake routes i think  match '/', :to => 'pages#home' will give the URL http://localhost:3000 not the http://localhost:3000/pages

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
root :to => 'pages#index'
```

like everyone said earlier but did You deleted *index.html.erb* from */public/* folder? Delete it and try again - this should resolve the problem :)